# Javascript inheritance and method with same name

Tags: javascript, inheritance, prototype

I have a basic question on prototype. I need to call a method of diferent object.

The 2 objects have the same named methods:

QuadForm.setdml()
QuadTable.setdml()

the question is how can i call setdml() of QuadTable on an instance of QuadForm.

when i do

```
window[o].wherePk = QuadTable.prototype.setDML(dataCopy, false, true);
```

then inside the method

```
var whereQ = obj.where_str;
obj.where_str = whereQ.replace(" AND ", "");
```

obj is not a quadForm type.
**The methods have the same name**...i am confused.
Thanks

Comment: `QuadTable.setdml.call(QuadForm)`?

Answer (score 0):

Solved

```
**window[o]['setDMLFromTable']=QuadTable.prototype.setDML;**
  window[o].wherePk=window[o].setDMLFromTable(dataCopy, false, true);
```